# jQuery change active class from a to li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We use some jQuery to make our navigation sticky from some point on the page and to add an active class to sections on the page. Currently the active class is added to the a class inside the li. But I want to add this to the li instead of the a href.

How can I achieve this?

Code:

```
<script>
$j(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $j('.menu-header-product'),
      scroll = $j(window).scrollTop();

  var elementOffset=jQuery("#productnav").offset();    
  if (scroll >= elementOffset.top - 57) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
$j(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $j('.content'),
      scroll = $j(window).scrollTop();

  var elementOffset=jQuery("#productnav").offset();    
  if (scroll >= elementOffset.top - 57) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        $j(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

        $j('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $j(document).off("scroll");

            $j('li').each(function () {
                $j(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            })
            $j(this).parent().addClass('active');

            var target = this.hash;
            $jtarget = $j(target);
            $j('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $jtarget.offset().top - 120 /**just subtract the height of the fixed html part */
             }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $j(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });
    });

function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPosition = $j(document).scrollTop();
        $j('nav li').each(function () {
            var currentLink = $j(this);
            var refElement = $j(currentLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top - 125 <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top - 125 + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
                $j('nav ul li a').parent().removeClass("active");
                currentLink.parent().addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currentLink.parent().removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `$j(this).addClass('active');` => `$j(this).parent("li").addClass('active');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) selector. So

```
$j(this).addClass('active');
```

becomes

```
$j(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

You would also need to change the selector `$j('a')` to `$j('li')`. I would recommend filtering to only `li`s in your navigation, i.e. `$j('nav li')`. Finally, you'd have to update the onScroll event similarly.

Comment: Well I tried it, see my new code above, but it does not seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using Dev tools to inspect the element (in chrome, right click > inspect element)? This will tell you which element the class is getting applied to. Perhaps the class is getting added but your CSS isn't?